# C#, Consuming multiple external API's/Services in one go sequentially

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, soap

I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement something for a website I'm trying to create.

There are some internally hosted SOAP services I want to consume, but I want to know what the best way of doing it is, the kicker is that certain elements from the response are required in the next request. I could (and have done previously) managed this but it wasn't very clean or clear.

I've spoken to some colleagues and I've had the Chain of Responsibility (CoR) design pattern mentioned but I'm not 100% sure if this is exactly what I need, and if it is I can't seem to visualise how this would work in my head given my current and limited understanding of it.

The flow will go something like this:

> User fills out a form which posts data items **FirstName**, **LastName**, **DOB**, **Postcode**

```
Service1 is then called with the above details in the request body
```

> Service1 responds with some other data, EG

```
<CustomerId>99999</CustomerId>
```

> Service2 then needs to be constructed with a body which itself requires the CustomerId node and others.

My understanding of the CoR is that it will pass the request on until it can find something to handle it, I'm trying to understand if this is the correct pattern to use of if I need to use something else?

I am also assuming best practice is to map the items I receive back in my service calls into objects as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think CoR will work for you.

This could be an implementation:

```
public class Request
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}

public class Response : Request
{
}

public class EntryPointService
{
    private readonly IService1 _service1;

    public EntryPointService(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, IService3 service3)
    {
        _service1 = service1;

        // Create your chain
        service1.RegisterNext(service2);
        service2.RegisterNext(service3);
        service3.RegisterNext(EndServiceHandler.Instance);
    }

    public Response Post(Request request)
    {
        // start your workflow
        var response =  _service1.TryToProcess(request);

        return response;
    }
}

public interface IChainProcessor
{
    void RegisterNext(IChainProcessor next);
    Response TryToProcess(Request request);
}

public interface IService1: IChainProcessor
{
}

public interface IService2: IChainProcessor
{
}

public interface IService3 : IChainProcessor
{
}


public class Service1: IService1
{
    private IChainProcessor _next = EndServiceHandler.Instance;

    public void RegisterNext(IChainProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Response TryToProcess(Request request)
    {
        var canProcess = true; // Add your validation logic here.

        if (!canProcess) return _next.TryToProcess(request);

        try
        {
            // Do your service1 workflow.

            // DoSomething1(request);
            // DoSomething2(request);         
        }
        catch (ChainProcessException e)
        {
            // If something is wrong, Log and stop your workflow.
            return new Response(); // <= add your return info here.
        }

        return _next.TryToProcess(request);
    }
}

// Null object pattern: End chain element
public class EndServiceHandler : IChainProcessor
{
    public static EndServiceHandler Instance { get; } = new EndServiceHandler();

    public void RegisterNext(IChainProcessor next)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Could not assign the next chain processor to the End of Workflow");
    }

    public Response TryToProcess(Request loanRequest)
    {
        // add here you invalid state.
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. All the services implementation are similar to Service1
2. You should manage the state of your request into the request object, do all necessary changes to it in every step, at the end mapping it to a response object.
3. If you want to stop the flow, you can do it in two ways:

   - Returning a Response object before to call _next.TryToProcess(request)
   - Throwing a ChainProcessException into the try-catch
4. The idea about stop the flow is for when you need to return validation messages, show unexpected errors, or go back for some extra info of the user.
5. You should never arrive at the EndServiceHandler, the flow should break before of that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of trying this, will upvote once I've had chance of trying to implement this